# Unable to make the image a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I get the following error :

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing
>   required keys: [:id]

Here is my code

```
       <% @posts.each do |x| %>
         <div class="white">    
            <%= link_to image_tag x.image.url(:medium), post_path %>
                <p>Published <%= time_ago_in_words(x.created_at)%>ago</p>

         <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

- you don't have the required param for the post_path
- the `link_to` and `image_tag` params are getting confused

Try this:

```
  <% @posts.each do |x| %>
     <div class="white">    
        <%= link_to image_tag(x.image.url(:medium)), post_path(x) %>
            <p>Published <%= time_ago_in_words(x.created_at)%>ago</p>

     <br>
```

The way that Ruby parses the nested calls the original way (without parentheses) is this:

```
link_to image_tag(x.image.url(:medium), post_path(x))
```

when you **clearly** mean this:

link_to image_tag(x.image.url(:medium)), post_path(x)

A set of parentheses will tell Ruby when one function's params stop and another's continue.

Comment: Done.  Sorry for the delay :)